# Why I'm not geting token in res in braintree?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, braintree

I'm using braintree for payment and I have done this.

```
gateway.customer.create({
    firstName: "Sachin",
    lastName: "Shah",
    company: "Qwerty",
    email: "Qwerty@example.com",
    phone: "114.555.1234",
    fax: "614.555.1234",
    website: "www.example.com",       
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.send({code:0, status:'Error', message:err});
    }else{
        res.send({code:1, status:'Success', data: result});
    }
});
```

I followed it's official [doc](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/node#payment_method_token) and they show that when req is success I'll get token but I'm gtting `result.customer.paymentMethods[]`

**Response**

```
{
"code": 1,
"status": "Success",
"data": {
    "customer": {
        "id": "569549779",
        "merchantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "firstName": "Sachin",
        "lastName": "Shah",
        "company": "Qwerty",
        "email": "Qwerty@example.com",
        "phone": "114.555.1234",
        "fax": "614.555.1234",
        "website": "www.example.com",
        "createdAt": "2019-10-10T05:13:42Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-10-10T05:13:42Z",
        "customFields": "",
        "globalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "creditCards": [],
        "addresses": [],
        "paymentMethods": []
    },
    "success": true
}
}
```

**Expected Output**

I need to get `paymentMethodToken` for further API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You're currently creating a customer without a payment method. You'll need to [create the customer with a payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create#customer-with-a-payment-method) to retrieve a `paymentMethodToken`.

Comment: Yes I read that. I have one doubt that should I have to do this each and every time ?

Comment: If you plan to charge the customer or create a subscription, you will always have to create the customer with a payment method.

Comment: So you mean If I want to make user's subscription for every month then I have to create a user every month ?